# Peak heap memory usage of an OCaml program

Tags: garbage-collection, ocaml

I would like to compute the peak memory usage of my OCaml program when it is running in compiled form as native code. I considered using the `stats` API in the `Gc` module, but it seems to return a snapshot at the time it is called. Is there some information in the `Gc` module or some other module that I can use to get peak heap usage just before my program terminates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current size of the major heap using `Gc.stat`, see the `live_words` field, multiply it by the word size in bytes to get the size in bytes (8 in a 64 bit system). It doesn't really matter but you can also add the size of the minor heap to the calculation, which is available via `Gc.get ()` see the `minor_heap_size` field (again in words).

You can create an alarm with `Gc.create_alarm` to check the size of the heap after each major collection to get the maximum size ever used.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful! Could you clarify why you say adding the size of the minor heap doesn't matter? Because it is small in comparison?

Comment: Yes, it's small and constant.

Comment: Note - `major_words` is the cumulative number of words allocated on the major heap including promotions. For peak usage, the values to track are `heap_words` or `live_words`.

Comment: @er0 thanks! Don't know why I wrote `major_words`!